# Showing unbiasedness in panel data with OLS

Tags: least-squares, panel-data

I need to show that OLS estimate is unbiased. I am familiar with OLS and the notation. However I found these equations in my material and I doubt whether this is correct. I understand that 'normally' an inverse term and a non inverse term multiplied, cancel each other out. It looks that that also has been done in the equations. However in this case, each individual has its own set of parameters, thus from my point of view, it's not allowed to cancel the double summations of the x's out, because the $\beta_i$ is within the summation.

$\mathrm{E}\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{t=1}^T x_{i t} x_{i t}^{\prime}\right)^{-1}\left(\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{t=1}^T x_{i t}\left(x_{i t}^{\prime} \beta_i+\varepsilon_{i t}\right)\right]=\right.$

$\mathrm{E}\left[\beta_i+\left(\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{t=1}^T x_{i t} x_{i t}^{\prime}\right)^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{t=1}^T x_{i t} \varepsilon_{i t}\right]$

Does my reasoning make sense, or did I miss anything?

Edit: I added the whole sub question

Consider the random-coefficient panel regression for $y_{i t}, t=1, \ldots, T$ and $i=1, \ldots, N$
$$
y_{i t}=x_{i t}^{\prime} \beta_i+\varepsilon_{i t}
$$
with $\varepsilon_{i t} \sim i . i . d .\left(0, \sigma_{\varepsilon}^2\right)$ and $\beta_i \sim i . i . d .\left(\beta, \Sigma_\beta\right)$ and where $x_{i t}$ is a $k$-dimensional vector of explanatory variables. To estimate $\beta$ we use OLS in the regression
$$
y_{i t}=x_{i t}^{\prime} \beta+u_{i t} \text {. }
$$

Is this OLS estimator unbiased?

Comment: I agree with your doubts, but typically the raison d'être of a panel analysis is that there is one coefficient vector in the panel, i.e. $\beta_i\equiv\beta$. Maybe there is a typo in your notes?

Comment: @ChristophHanck Thanks for your quick response. I posted the whole sub question for clarification. The DGP contains the subindex I, which means that in reality each individual has a own set of parameters. We try to estimate this with a model that contains a "general" set of parameters,

Comment: OK, thanks. Unbiased for what, then - if each unit has its own parameters which differ and the estimator only produces one value, it is hard to see how it could be unbiased for several values at the same time?

Comment: @ChristophHanck Given the second expectation equation, it is clear that the second terms disappears since the error is 0 in expectation.  If we accept that the first term is reduced to $\beta_i$, we see that this is $E[\beta_i]$ = $\beta$. This follows from the extra information about the distribution of $\beta_i$. Hence unbiased

Comment: I find it hard to come up with a clear argumentation why $\beta_i$ does not 'participate' in the double summation. My only thought is that the notation 'i' as index for beta is chosen a bit unfortunate, so that we could as well have chosen $\gamma$ to clearify that it does not participate in the double summation

Comment: I would try to work with the law of iterated expectations and use, if true, that the distribution of the $\beta_i$ is independent of $x_i$